# Make browser default to using cache rather than connecting

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I created a web app with HTML and JavaScript. One of the key features I want the app to have is to be accessible offline. I use [cache manifest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) to cache the pages and can later be accessed offline. (The cache manifest file contains all pages and I have the

```
<html manifest="example">
```

in every page's header).

This worked out well; when not connected to internet I can still browse through the pages.

My issue comes when connecting to a different network (my web server is on my local network only). If I connect to a different network everything fails. The browser gives a connection error.

Is there a way to have the browser default to using the cache rather than trying to connect?
(I'm using this on Firefox on Android)

cache.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 01-SEP-13 215 
CACHE:

# CSS
css/mystyle.css
css/custom-theme/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css

# IMAGES
images/logo.jpg

#CONTENT
content/testPage1.html

# DATA
data/projectData.json

# JQUERY
js/jquery/js/jquery-1.10.1.js
js/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js
js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js
js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js
js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

# settings  JS
js/testScript.js
js/add.js


 # html
firstPage.html
about.html
contact.html

NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: I think the cache has priority, except if you state otherwise. Please post your manifest file.

Comment: @alkins hm. Is there a place where you can specify its priority? I added my manifest file to the question.

Comment: `my web server is on my local network only` This part jumped out at me. How are you connecting (URL) to your website when you are on your home network? How are you connecting (URL) to it when you on a different network?

Comment: @Adam I'm connecting with the ip address of the webserver (don't cringe if that is a stupid way).

Comment: What I mean by priority is everything you specify in Cache: segment will fetched by the cache. What do you mean by connection error? What is it trying to fetch from the server and fails?

Comment: Adam may be on to something here. If you are using a different url then that's the problem

Comment: @alkis sometimes, it happens randomly, when I navigate through the pages while connected to ANOTHER network other than the one where the web server is housed I get a connection error (The server took too long to respond error). I'm not sure what its trying to get from the server...that's my issue. I want it to rely on the cache to load the page rather than connection to the web server to retrieve the pages. And I'm not using a different URL.